# Java threads not executed concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to automate some kind of exhaustive password in Java, using threads to split the task in four pieces.

For some reason, when the following line

```
t0 = new password(0,1,0);
```

is executed, the program doesn't go past beyond that. That is, it runs the thread before having even been called with the start() method.

In this case, parallelism doesn't work at all. Trying to stop the thread doesn't work either.

```
package password;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class password extends Thread {

    String[] l1 = {"w","e","r","s","f","x","c","v"};
    String[] l2 = {"u","o","j","k","l"};
    String[] l3 = {"a","s","d","y","c"};
    String[] l4 = {"i","o","p","k","é"};
    String[] l5 = {"w","e","r"};
    String[] l6 = {"q","w"};
    String[] l7 = {"e","r","t"};
    String[] l8 = {"e","t","d","f","g"};
    String[] l9 = {"z","u","i","h","k","n","m"};
    String[] l10 = {"q","e","a","s","d"};
    String[] l11 = {"q","w"};
    String[] l12 = {"r","t","z"};
    String[] l13 = {"i","o","p"};
    String[] l14 = {"h","j","k","n"};
    String[] l15 = {"w","a","s"};
    String[] l16 = {"o","è","l","é","a"};
    String[] l17 = {"q","w","e"};
    String[] l18 = {"t","z","u"};
    String[] l19 = {"r","t","z"};

    public password(int x, int y, int z) throws IOException{

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream("Z:/key"+"z"+".txt"), "utf-8"));

        new Thread(){
            int counter = 0, counter2 = 0;
            public void run() {}{
                for(int a = x; a<y; a++){
                    for(int b = 0; b<5; b++){
                        for(int c = 0; c<5; c++){
                            for(int d = 0; d<5; d++){
                                for(int e = 0; e<3; e++){
                                    for(int f = 0; f<2; f++){
                                        for(int g = 0; g<3; g++){
                                            for(int h = 0; h<5; h++){
                                                for(int i = 0; i<7; i++){
                                                    for(int j = 0; j<5; j++){
                                                        for(int k = 0; k<2; k++){
                                                            for(int l = 0; l<3; l++){
                                                                for(int m = 0; m<3; m++){
                                                                    for(int n = 0; n<4; n++){
                                                                        for(int o = 0; o<3; o++){
                                                                            for(int p = 0; p<5; p++){
                                                                                for(int q = 0; q<3; q++){
                                                                                    for(int r = 0; r<3; r++){
                                                                                        for(int s = 0; s<3; s++){
                                                                                            writer.write(new String(l1[a]+l2[b]+l3[c]+l4[d]+l5[e]+l6[f]+l7[g]+l8[h]+l9[i]+l10[j]+l11[k]+l12[l]+l13[m]+l14[n]+l15[o]+l16[p]+l17[q]+l18[r]+l19[s]));
                                                                                            writer.newLine();
                                                                                            counter++;
                                                                                            if(((counter%1000000) == 0) && counter!=0){
                                                                                                counter2++;
                                                                                                System.out.println("r0" + counter2);
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            Thread.yield();
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                writer.close();
            }
        };
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        password t0,t1,t2,t3;
        t0 = new password(0,1,0);
        t1 = new password(2,3,1);
        t2 = new password(4,5,2);
        t3 = new password(6,7,3);
        System.out.println("asd");

        long tiem = System.nanoTime();
        t0.start();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        long anodertiem = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Time taken: " + (anodertiem-tiem)/1000000);
    }

}
```

Comment: From `Thread.yield();` "It is rarely appropriate to use this method.". Nice set of loops though.

Comment: There's no need to create a new Thread inside your password class. The password object IS already a thread. So you should implement a run() method directly inside the password class.

Comment: @Kayaman I changed it to 'yield();'. Thanks
user1717259: Will do, thanks.

Comment: @Dreadlockyx With "it's rarely appropriate to use this method" I (or the javadoc rather) meant you don't need the call at all. It's like `InputStream.available();`, you don't need it, but people misuse it because they think it does something it doesn't.

Comment: @Kayaman I actually saw that call in a manual in french on how to do multitasking in Java, so they might've been wrong. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `run()` method is closed **without** any code.

```
        public void run() {} // The method is already closed here...
```

What follows, is a code block which is executed during Object creation.

```
{
   // Many nested for loops.
}
```

Don't close your run method (just remove the unnecessary closing brace).

Comment: That was it, indeed. Now I see the start method does nothing, but that's another issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You perform all operations in the constructor.
You should move these to the run() method instead.

Also, it's a bit weird you start a new thread in a thread class.
You don't need that.

For more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html